# Apache Lucene update from 4.6.0 to 4.7.0 - corruptindexexception codec header mismatch

Tags: java, lucene

after upgrade apache lucene from 4.6. to 4.7. I get the exception:

```
ERROR 05.03.14 12:55:18.567  com.bla.bla.bla.SearchQueryServiceLuceneImpl@init: error building dictionary
    org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: codec header mismatch: actual header=-680782077 vs expected header=1071082519 (resource:                       org.apache.lucene.store.InputStreamDataInput@519f6b)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeader(CodecUtil.java:128)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.FST.<init>(FST.java:318)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.FST.<init>(FST.java:304)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.analyzing.AnalyzingSuggester.load(AnalyzingSuggester.java:590)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.Lookup.load(Lookup.java:175)
```

When I do the following

```
        File dictFile = new File(getLuceneIndexFilePath().getCanonicalPath()+File.separator+"LSG_Dictionary.dic");
        LOG.debug("expecting Lucene dictionary here: " + dictFile.getAbsolutePath());
        suggester.load(new FileInputStream(dictFile));
        LOG.debug("loaded existing dictionary");
```

On the load Functioncall. The index was build with a previous version!

Any Ideas why?

Comment: It might that after updateing something changed in Suggestor (Lookup). If I got an Error while trying to load the dic file, I delete it and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to updgrader your index using this class:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html

Basically the index files carry the codec information and code header has the version number information. This needs to be upgarded for IndexReaders of Lucene 4.7 codec to be able to read the index.